# Issues with loading BQ clustered table

Tags: google-bigquery

When I am trying to load data from existing Partitioned table to new Clustered table in Bigquery, I see below error.

```
Failed to copy Natural partitioned table to Natural partitioned clustering table: not supported
```

Any inputs please.

Comment: can you give us more details - how are you performing this operation?

Comment: I am seeing error When I am trying to load data from existing Partitioned table to new Clustered table in Bigquery.
When I use insert statement, I see Omitting "INSERT target column list is unsupported for ingestion-time partitioned table" error.
Any solutions please

Comment: So that error is very different to the one posted in the question. Can you post a new complete question, including what instructions you are running, what errors you are getting, and a way for us to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Note, BigQuery supports few kinds of [partitions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables):

- Ingestion time: Tables are partitioned based on the data's ingestion (load) date or arrival date.
- Date/timestamp: Tables are partitioned based on a TIMESTAMP or DATE column.
- Integer range:  This feature is in a pre-release state

Tables can only be partitioned by one field, which must be a timestamp or date column, and clustered by a single set of columns.

Prerequisites:

- When performing this process, you must have the permissions outlined in [BigQuery’s documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#required_permissions).
- When you use the clustered table feature with a partitioned table, you are subject to the [limits on partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#partitioned_tables).
- Quotas and limits also apply to the different types of jobs you can run against clustered tables, including [loading data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs) (load jobs), what happens in your case.
- Take a look for [creating clustered tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables) in BigQuery.

If all of the source tables are partitioned tables, the partition specifications for all source tables must match the destination table's partition specification. The source and destination tables must be in datasets in the same location.

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through this documents. I am seeing error When I am trying to load data from existing Partitioned table to new Clustered table in Bigquery.

Comment: I am seeing error When I am trying to load data from existing Partitioned table to new Clustered table in Bigquery.
When I use insert statement, I see Omitting "INSERT target column list is unsupported for ingestion-time partitioned table" error.
Any solutions please

Comment: As @Felipe Hoffa said in comment, please put this error in a new question and describe steps you have taken so far, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per [https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables](http://CREATE%20TABLE%20%20%20%20mydataset.myclusteredtable%20%20PARTITION%20BY%20%20%20%20DATE(timestamp)%20%20CLUSTER%20BY%20%20%20%20clustering_column%20AS%20%20SELECT%20%20%20%20*%20%20FROM%20%20%20%20%60mydataset.mytable%60)
you can create the table as :

```
CREATE TABLE
   mydataset.myclusteredtable
 PARTITION BY
   DATE(timestamp)
 CLUSTER BY
   clustering_column AS
 SELECT
   *
 FROM
   `mydataset.mytable`
```

NOTE: Only standard SQL is supported for querying clustered tables and for writing query results to clustered tables.

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through this documents. I am seeing error When I am trying to load data from existing Partitioned table to new Clustered table in Bigquery.

Comment: I am seeing error When I am trying to load data from existing Partitioned table to new Clustered table in Bigquery.
When I use insert statement, I see Omitting "INSERT target column list is unsupported for ingestion-time partitioned table" error.
Any solutions please

Comment: @melgeek Can you post your solution, what have you tried to help us understand better? Now also are you getting the same error you posted in the question ?